# relational fields of the same model [ODOO 10 ]

Tags: odoo-10

is it possible to use a relational field of the own model i've worked?

For example
_name = 'x.x'
x_ids = fields.Many2many('x.x')

I need to show the records I've created of the same model in relation field, any suggestions?

Comment: Yes this is possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is entirely possible, and you can use relational ways exactly the same way then you would do it with an another model.

Comment: Hi, i tried but it doesn't work.                                                    AssertionError: project.task.depend_on: Implicit/canonical naming of many2many relationship table is not possible when source and destination models are the same

Comment: You probably need to explicitly provide each part of the field definition. E.g. `fields.Many2many('src_model', 'src_model_rel', 'field_1', 'field_2')`

Comment: hi, i have a new problem, when in the form view I add : editable="bottom"  not save the data. [                                       depend_id = fields.Many2many(
        comodel_name='project.task',
        relation='project_task1_rel',
        column1='col_name',
        column2='col_name_2',
        store=True
    )]